# Python + OpenGL = "Command terminated"

Tags: python, opengl

I'm on Ubuntu, with Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) [GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
with OpenGL version 3.0.0

and I've just downloaded http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyOpenGL-Demo.

I ran the first example in NeHe directory, lesson11.pym without modify it.

```
Hit ESC key to quit.

Command terminated
```

What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have working 3d support? My guess is no. OpenGL isn't going to work without it.

Comment: sorry, what is it? how can i know if i have working 3d support?

Comment: `glxgears` is probably the canonical test app.

Comment: i downloaded a glxgear example in pure c, and it's ok, in java with JOGL and it's ok, .. in python, same error